# bound on trace-norm of product of matrices

Tags: matrices, inequality, normed-spaces

Is it true that 
$$
\|ABA^\dagger\|_1\leq \|A\|^2\|B\|_1,
$$
where $\|A\|_1$ is the trace norm, $\|A\|$ is the spectral norm, and $A$ and $B$ are square matrices?

Answer (score 2):

The ordered singular values of two matrices $X$ and $Y$ satisfy $\sigma_i(XY)\leq\sigma_i(X)\|Y\|$. Since the trace norm of $X$ is given by the sum of its singular values, we have (I hope $^\dagger$ is the transposition here)
$$
\|ABA^{\dagger}\|_1=\sum_{i=1}^n\sigma_i(ABA^{\dagger})\leq\sum_{i=1}^n\sigma_i(BA^{\dagger})\|A\|\leq\sum_{i=1}^n\sigma_i(B)\|A\|^2=\|A\|^2\|B\|_1.
$$